# Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Object

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I created a simple entity with a property of type Object, because I can't control its type, it can be String or an object.

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "myCollection", clientName = "mongoClient1")
public class MyClass extends EntityId {
   private String name;
   private Int age;
   private Object payload;

   //Getters and Setters
   ...
}
```

I am trying to insert but the following error is occurring:

> Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Object

I tried to change the property to Document, BsonDocument and BsonValue but when its value is of type String another exception occurs because it is not possible to deserialize string for these types.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: The issue you're facing is related to MongoDB's object mapping and serialization. When you use the type `Object` for the payload property, MongoDB's default codec doesn't know how to handle it since `Object` **is a very generic type** that can represent various data types. Have you considered using the `Document` class?

Comment: I tried using Document, when the property value is an object it even works but when it's a String it throws an exception.

> javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to deserialize property 'payload' because of: Error deserialize JSON value into type: class org.bson.Document.

Comment: @DiegoBorba, So can i create a codec where mongoDb learns to serialize and deserialize an object, right?

Comment: Sure! You can use `MongoClientSettings.codecRegistry(*codecHere*)`.

Comment: I did using RegisterForReflection to register my codec, I'll post an answer showing how it turned out. thanks @DiegoBorba for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @DiegoBorda's tip and after doing extensive research and discussion with ChatGPT I came up with a solution that worked for me.

I am sharing this solution because other people might encounter the same issue.

I created an `ObjectCodec` implemented as a `Codec`.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.bson.BsonReader;
import org.bson.BsonType;
import org.bson.BsonWriter;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.DecoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.types.Decimal128;

public class ObjectCodec implements Codec<Object> {

    @Override
    public void encode(BsonWriter writer, Object value, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
        writeValue(writer, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Object> getEncoderClass() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
        return readValue(reader);
    }

    private static Object readValue(BsonReader bsonReader) {
        var type = bsonReader.getCurrentBsonType();
        switch (type) {
            case ARRAY:
                ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
                bsonReader.readStartArray();
                while (bsonReader.readBsonType() != BsonType.END_OF_DOCUMENT) {
                    array.add(readValue(bsonReader));
                }
                bsonReader.readEndArray();
                return array;
            case BINARY:
                return bsonReader.readBinaryData();
            case BOOLEAN:
                return bsonReader.readBoolean();
            case DATE_TIME:
                return bsonReader.readDateTime();
            case DB_POINTER:
                return bsonReader.readDBPointer();
            case DECIMAL128:
                return bsonReader.readDecimal128();
            case DOCUMENT:
                HashMap<String, Object> nestedMap = new HashMap<>();
                bsonReader.readStartDocument();
                while (bsonReader.readBsonType() != BsonType.END_OF_DOCUMENT) {
                    nestedMap.put(bsonReader.readName(), readValue(bsonReader));
                }
                bsonReader.readEndDocument();
                return nestedMap;
            case DOUBLE:
                return bsonReader.readDouble();
            case INT32:
                return bsonReader.readInt32();
            case INT64:
                return bsonReader.readInt64();
            case NULL:
                return null;
            case OBJECT_ID:
                return bsonReader.readObjectId();
            case STRING:
                return bsonReader.readString();
            case TIMESTAMP:
                return bsonReader.readTimestamp();
            case UNDEFINED:
                return null;
            default:
                return null;

        }
    }

    private static void writeValue(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof String) {
            bsonWriter.writeString(value.toString());
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            bsonWriter.writeInt32((Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            bsonWriter.writeInt64((Long) value);
        } else if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
            bsonWriter.writeDecimal128(Decimal128.parse(value.toString()));
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            bsonWriter.writeDouble((Double) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            bsonWriter.writeBoolean((Boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof HashMap) {
            // Recursively handle HashMap for nesting
            bsonWriter.writeStartDocument();
            HashMap<?, ?> nestedMap = (HashMap<?, ?>) value;
            for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : nestedMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey().toString();
                Object nestedValue = entry.getValue();
                bsonWriter.writeName(key);
                writeValue(bsonWriter, nestedValue);
            }
            bsonWriter.writeEndDocument();
        } else if (value instanceof ArrayList) {
            ArrayList<?> arrayList = (ArrayList<?>) value;
            bsonWriter.writeStartArray();
            for (Object item : arrayList) {
                writeValue(bsonWriter, item);
            }
            bsonWriter.writeEndArray();
        } else if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
            bsonWriter.writeStartArray();
            int length = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(value);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Object item = java.lang.reflect.Array.get(value, i);
                writeValue(bsonWriter, item);
            }
            bsonWriter.writeEndArray();
        } else {
            try {
                Class<?> clazz = value.getClass();
                bsonWriter.writeStartDocument();
                while (clazz != null) {
                    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
                    for (Field field : fields) {
                        int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
                        if (!java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)) {
                            field.setAccessible(true);
                            String fieldName = field.getName();
                            if (fieldName.equals("id")) {
                                fieldName = "_id";
                            }
                            Object fieldValue = field.get(value);
                            bsonWriter.writeName(fieldName);
                            writeValue(bsonWriter, fieldValue);
                        }
                    }
                    clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
                }
                bsonWriter.writeEndDocument();

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a Custom Codec Provider by instantiating my ObjectCodec.

```java
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecProvider;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@RegisterForReflection
public class CustomCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {
    private final Codec<Object> objectCodec;

    public CustomCodecProvider() {
        // Create an instance of the custom ObjectCodec and pass the default CodecRegistry for internal use, if needed.
        this.objectCodec = new ObjectCodec();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry) {
        // Check if the type is Object and return the custom ObjectCodec.
        if (clazz == Object.class) {
            return (Codec<T>) objectCodec;
        }
        return null; // If the type is not Object, return null to let other default MongoDB codecs be used.
    }
}
```

Then I had to register the CustomCodecProvider in my `application.properties`.

```
quarkus:
  mongodb:
    codec-providers: br.com.api.infra.crosscutting.ioc.config.CustomCodecProvider
```

This is working for me, but if anyone has other solutions, I'd like to try them out.